# Splitting a dictionary in python based on memory size

Tags: python, http, memory, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm in the process of moving a distributed file system into aws simpledb using boto, and I'm running into an issue that doesn't have a clear solution to me. The current state of my code is as follows:

```
def insert(documents):
    data = {hash_doc(d): _decode(d) for d in documents if hash_doc(d)}
    domain.batch_put_attributes(data)
```

Basically the issue that I'm hitting is that the request up to aws made in the `batch_put_attributes` function has a maximum size of 1MB. Obviously I want to minimize the number of requests I'm making, but I also can't hit the 1MB limit.

Is there any nice pythonic way to basically say

> Split this iterable into chunks that are all below a certain memory
>   size, but as few chunks as possible

I feel a little bad for not including more code, but I just haven't found something that tractable on this one and I feel like there should be a pretty straightforward solution.

Comment: I cant think of a straight forward solution. But did you try to play around with sys.getsizeof(VAR_NAME) to try and do the chunking yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like the following to preprocess it a bit:

```
size_d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in data.items(): 
    size_d[sys.getsizeof(v)].append(v)
```

Then just make a function to fill up a 1MB bucket of items, pop any item that you decide to send so you don't reuse it. Could probably optimize it a bit by sorting the items by size. Pretty sure this is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) so if you find an optimal solution let us all know :)

Comment: Not quite the knapsack problem, and this answer kind of misunderstands the question. There is a constraint here that the items in each request must appear sequentially. This is adaptive, yet sequential list chunking, not the knapsack problem.

Comment: My bad. Misunderstood the sequential aspect. Do you mean that the sequence restraint is on your specific problem and you need to upload the chunks such that you don't upload the item at idx 200 before idx 105?

Comment: so if the original order is [a,b,c,d,e,f,g...] can you send two buckets looking like [a,c,e] and [b,d,g] and [f, ...] or does the order need to be preserved between buckets?

Comment: Order is preserved between buckets